# Need Help in writing GEKKO Python optimization code to for the following bio-model database SBML model

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gekko

I want to find the optimized value of x1 for which x21 will be maximize for the following attached sbml model downloaded from biomodel database. I need to use GEKKO python code for the same. As i am new to python, please help me with the code. Also i need to know that how the units are taken care of in GEKKO python. As it consists of non-linear differential equations with some initial values as percentage, how to deal with that.

https://www.ebi.ac.uk/biomodels/BIOMD0000000137#Files

Comment: Please show directly your code, input and wanted output instead of a link. You should also show some research effort and what you've trued. I strongly suggest you read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I have a different code, I posted this as m looking for help to write the code that contains such events and assignment rules. As I am new to python, it's quite difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [converter tool](https://model.caltech.edu/software/converters/#from-sbml) to translate from SBML to an APMonitor Model. Gekko can use APMonitor files with the `m.Raw()` command.

Here is the output using [System Biology Format Converter (SBFC) Online](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/biomodels/tools/converters/).

```matlab
! This file is automatically generated with 
! the System Biology Format Converter (http://sbfc.sourceforge.net/)
! from an SBML file.
!
! Model name = Sedaghat2002_InsulinSignalling_noFeedback
!
! is http://identifiers.org/biomodels.db/MODEL6526728774
! is http://identifiers.org/biomodels.db/BIOMD0000000137
! isDescribedBy http://identifiers.org/pubmed/12376338
! isDerivedFrom http://identifiers.org/biomodels.db/MODEL1201140005
! isDerivedFrom http://identifiers.org/biomodels.db/MODEL1201140006
! isDerivedFrom http://identifiers.org/pubmed/1890850
! isDerivedFrom http://identifiers.org/pubmed/1890848
! isDerivedFrom http://identifiers.org/pubmed/8304439
!

Model 
! Compartments
!   CellSurfa=1.0! Compartment: id = CellSurface, name = CellSurface, constant
!   Intracell=1.0! Compartment: id = Intracellular, name = Intracellular, constant
! End Compartments
 Parameters 
    k1=6.0E-8   ! Parameter:   id =  k1, name = k1, constant
    kminus1=0.2 ! Parameter:   id =  kminus1, name = kminus1, constant
    k2=6.0E-8   ! Parameter:   id =  k2, name = k2, constant
    kminus2=20.0    ! Parameter:   id =  kminus2, name = kminus2, constant
    k3=2500.0   ! Parameter:   id =  k3, name = k3, constant
    kminus3=0.2 ! Parameter:   id =  kminus3, name = kminus3, constant
    k4=3.3333334E-4 ! Parameter:   id =  k4, name = k4, constant
    kminus4=0.003   ! Parameter:   id =  kminus4, name = kminus4, constant
    k4prime=0.0021  ! Parameter:   id =  k4prime, name = k4prime, constant
    kminus4pr=2.1E-4    ! Parameter:   id =  kminus4prime, name = kminus4prime, constant
    k5=0.0  ! Parameter:   id =  k5, name = k5
    kminus5=1.67E-18    ! Parameter:   id =  kminus5, name = kminus5, constant
    k6=0.461    ! Parameter:   id =  k6, name = k6, constant
    k7=4.16 ! Parameter:   id =  k7, name = k7, constant
    kminus7=1.396   ! Parameter:   id =  kminus7, name = kminus7, constant
    k8=7.06E-4  ! Parameter:   id =  k8, name = k8, constant
    kminus8=10.0    ! Parameter:   id =  kminus8, name = kminus8, constant
    k9_stimul=1.39  ! Parameter:   id =  k9_stimulated, name = k9_stimulated, constant
    k9_basal=0.13145    ! Parameter:   id =  k9_basal, name = k9_basal, constant
    kminus9=42.15   ! Parameter:   id =  kminus9, name = kminus9, constant
    k10=2.961   ! Parameter:   id =  k10, name = k10, constant
    kminus10=2.77   ! Parameter:   id =  kminus10, name = kminus10, constant
    kminus11=6.9315 ! Parameter:   id =  kminus11, name = kminus11, constant
    kminus12=6.9315 ! Parameter:   id =  kminus12, name = kminus12, constant
    k13=0.00696 ! Parameter:   id =  k13, name = k13, constant
    kminus13=0.167  ! Parameter:   id =  kminus13, name = kminus13, constant
    k14=0.11088 ! Parameter:   id =  k14, name = k14, constant
    kminus14=0.001155   ! Parameter:   id =  kminus14, name = kminus14, constant
    IRp=897.0   ! Parameter:   id =  IRp, name = IRp, constant
    SHIP=1.0    ! Parameter:   id =  SHIP, name = SHIP, constant
    PTEN=1.0    ! Parameter:   id =  PTEN, name = PTEN, constant
    PTP=1.0 ! Parameter:   id =  PTP, name = PTP, constant
    APequil=9.09091 ! Parameter:   id =  APequil, name = APequil, constant
    PI3K=5.0    ! Parameter:   id =  PI3K, name = PI3K, constant
 End Parameters 

 Variables
    x1=1.0E8    !Is not affected by rule or reaction    ! Species:   id = x1, name = Insulin; Compartment:CellSurface
! Warning species is not changed by either rules or reactions
! Species is changed by 1 event(s)
    x2=900.0    !init   ! Species:   id = x2, name = Unbound Insulin Receptor; Compartment:CellSurface, affected by kineticLaw
    x3=0.0  !init   ! Species:   id = x3, name = Unphosphorylated once bound receptor; Compartment:CellSurface, affected by kineticLaw
    x5=0.0  !init   ! Species:   id = x5, name = Phosphorylated once bound receptor; Compartment:CellSurface, affected by kineticLaw
    x4=0.0  !init   ! Species:   id = x4, name = Phosphorylated twice bound receptor; Compartment:CellSurface, affected by kineticLaw
    x6=100.0    !init   ! Species:   id = x6, name = Unbound unphosphorylated intracellular receptor; Compartment:Intracellular, affected by kineticLaw
    x7=0.0  !init   ! Species:   id = x7, name = Phosphorylated twice bound intracellular receptor; Compartment:Intracellular, affected by kineticLaw
    x8=0.0  !init   ! Species:   id = x8, name = Phosphorylated once bound intracellular receptor; Compartment:Intracellular, affected by kineticLaw
    x9=1000.0   !init   ! Species:   id = x9, name = Unphosphorylated IRS1; Compartment:Intracellular, affected by kineticLaw
    x10=0.0 !init   ! Species:   id = x10, name = Phosphorylated IRS1; Compartment:Intracellular, affected by kineticLaw
    x11=100.0   !init   ! Species:   id = x11, name = PI3 Kinase; Compartment:Intracellular, affected by kineticLaw
    x12=0.0 !init   ! Species:   id = x12, name = IRS1- PI3 Kinase Complex; Compartment:Intracellular, affected by kineticLaw
    x13=0.31    !init   ! Species:   id = x13, name = PI3,4,5P3; Compartment:Intracellular, affected by kineticLaw
    x14=99.4    !init   ! Species:   id = x14, name = PI4,5P2; Compartment:Intracellular, affected by kineticLaw
    x15=0.29    !init   ! Species:   id = x15, name = PI3,4P2; Compartment:Intracellular, affected by kineticLaw
    x16=100.0   !init   ! Species:   id = x16, name = Unactivated Akt; Compartment:Intracellular, affected by kineticLaw
    x17=0.0 !init   ! Species:   id = x17, name = Activated Akt; Compartment:Intracellular, affected by kineticLaw
    x18=100.0   !init   ! Species:   id = x18, name = Unactivated PKC; Compartment:Intracellular, affected by kineticLaw
    x19=0.0 !init   ! Species:   id = x19, name = Activated PKC; Compartment:Intracellular, affected by kineticLaw
    x20=96.0    !init   ! Species:   id = x20, name = Intracellular GLUT4; Compartment:Intracellular, affected by kineticLaw
    x21=4.0 !init   ! Species:   id = x21, name = Cell surface GLUT4; Compartment:CellSurface, affected by kineticLaw
 End Variables

 Intermediates
    k9=(k9_stimul+k9_basal)*x12/PI3K+k9_basal   !assignmentRule: Variable = k9
    k11=0.1*kminus11*(x13-0.31)/(3.1-0.31)  !assignmentRule: Variable = k11
    k12=0.1*kminus12*(x13-0.31)/(3.1-0.31)  !assignmentRule: Variable = k12
    Effect=(0.2*x17+0.8*x19)/APequil    !assignmentRule: Variable = Effect
    k13prime=(40/60-4/96)*kminus13*Effect   !assignmentRule: Variable = k13prime
    x4x5=x4+x5  !assignmentRule: Variable = x4x5

    R1=CellSurfa*(k1*x1*x2-kminus1*x3)  ! Reaction: id = R1 ! name = Insulin binding
    R2=CellSurfa*k3*x3  ! Reaction: id = R2 ! name = Receptor Autophosphorylation
    R3=CellSurfa*k2*x1*x5-kminus2*x4    ! Reaction: id = R3 ! name = Insulin Binding
    R4=CellSurfa*kminus3*PTP*x5 ! Reaction: id = R4 ! name = Receptor dephosphorylation
    R5=CellSurfa*(k4*x2-kminus4*x6) ! Reaction: id = R5 ! name = Receptor endocytosis
    R6=CellSurfa*(k4prime*x4-kminus4pr*x7)  ! Reaction: id = R6 ! name = Receptor transport
    R7=CellSurfa*(k4prime*x5-kminus4pr*x8)  ! Reaction: id = R7 ! name = Receptor transport
    R8=Intracell*k5 ! Reaction: id = R8 ! name = Receptor synthesis
    R9=Intracell*kminus5*x6 ! Reaction: id = R9 ! name = Receptor degradation
    R10=Intracell*k6*PTP*x7 ! Reaction: id = R10    ! name = Intracellular receptor dephosphorylation
    R11=Intracell*k6*PTP*x8 ! Reaction: id = R11    ! name = Intracellular receptor dephosphorylation
    R12=Intracell*(k7*x9*(x4+x5)/IRp-kminus7*PTP*x10)   ! Reaction: id = R12    ! name = IRS1 activation
    R13=Intracell*(k8*x10*x11-kminus8*x12)  ! Reaction: id = R13    ! name = IRS1-PI3K complex formation
    R14=Intracell*(k9*x14-kminus9*PTEN*x13) ! Reaction: id = R14    ! name = PI 3,4,5 P3 generation
    R15=Intracell*(k10*x15-kminus10*SHIP*x13)   ! Reaction: id = R15    ! name = PI 3,4,5P3 generation
    R16=Intracell*(k11*x16-kminus11*x17)    ! Reaction: id = R16    ! name = Akt activation
    R17=Intracell*(k12*x18-kminus12*x19)    ! Reaction: id = R17    ! name = PKC activation
    R18=Intracell*k14   ! Reaction: id = R18    ! name = GLUT4 synthesis
    R19=Intracell*kminus14*x20  ! Reaction: id = R19    ! name = GLUT4 degradation
    R20=Intracell*((k13+k13prime)*x20-kminus13*x21) ! Reaction: id = R20    ! name = GLUT4 translocation
 End Intermediates

 Equations
    $x2=(1/(CellSurfa))*((-1.0 * R1) + ( 1.0 * R4) + (-1.0 * R5))
    $x3=(1/(CellSurfa))*(( 1.0 * R1) + (-1.0 * R2))
    $x5=(1/(CellSurfa))*(( 1.0 * R2) + (-1.0 * R3) + (-1.0 * R4) + (-1.0 * R7))
    $x4=(1/(CellSurfa))*(( 1.0 * R3) + (-1.0 * R6))
    $x6=(1/(Intracell))*(( 1.0 * R5) + ( 1.0 * R8) + (-1.0 * R9) + ( 1.0 * R10) + ( 1.0 * R11))
    $x7=(1/(Intracell))*(( 1.0 * R6) + (-1.0 * R10))
    $x8=(1/(Intracell))*(( 1.0 * R7) + (-1.0 * R11))
    $x9=(1/(Intracell))*((-1.0 * R12))
    $x10=(1/(Intracell))*(( 1.0 * R12) + (-1.0 * R13))
    $x11=(1/(Intracell))*((-1.0 * R13))
    $x12=(1/(Intracell))*(( 1.0 * R13))
    $x13=(1/(Intracell))*(( 1.0 * R14) + ( 1.0 * R15))
    $x14=(1/(Intracell))*((-1.0 * R14))
    $x15=(1/(Intracell))*((-1.0 * R15))
    $x16=(1/(Intracell))*((-1.0 * R16))
    $x17=(1/(Intracell))*(( 1.0 * R16))
    $x18=(1/(Intracell))*((-1.0 * R17))
    $x19=(1/(Intracell))*(( 1.0 * R17))
    $x20=(1/(Intracell))*(( 1.0 * R18) + (-1.0 * R19) + (-1.0 * R20))
    $x21=(1/(CellSurfa))*(( 1.0 * R20))
 End Equations


! event : event_0000001
event_000=if (t >= 15) then (1.5) else (0.2)
global 1 {event_000 - 1.1} {x1=0}

! event : event_0000002
event_0_1=if ((x6+x7+x8) > 100) then (1.5) else (0.2)
global 1 {event_0_1 - 1.1} {k5=1.67E-2}

! event : event_0000003
event_0_2=if ((x6+x7+x8) <= 100) then (1.5) else (0.2)
global 1 {event_0_2 - 1.1} {k5=0.1002}

End Model
!Parameter Count:34
!Variable Count:21
!Intermediate Count:26
!Equation Count:21
```

You need to replace the events with relevant input data to tell Gekko when the steps in values need to occur. More information on Gekko is provided in the [documentation](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [ODE examples](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/PythonDifferentialEquations), and [other Gekko examples](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/GekkoPythonOptimization).

Comment: Thanks a lot sir...But I have already tried this, m facing the issue with writing the assignment rules and events in python. I don't know how will it be taking the input. Also, how to make an objective function for which values of X1 we get x21 maximized.

Comment: You can maximize with `m.Maximize(X1)` and `m.Maximize(x21)`. Please see the documentation for examples of how to change the inputs. Here is one example of changing the input from 0 to 1 at time step 5: `x = m.Param([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1])`.